# How to resolve same FDQN to two different AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to have "www.example.com" resolve to an API Gateway and "www.example.com/assests" resolve to CloudFront?

Comment: I think you could accomplish this by using your API Gateway as a cloudfront origin right? Then just always route to cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to have a single subdomain DNS record resolve to two different things based on the path, since the path is not part of what the DNS server handles.

The solution here is to point your subdomain at your CloudFront distribution, and configure it with two origins, API Gateway being the default origin, and whatever `/assest` is (an S3 bucket?) as the origin for the `/assets/*` path.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am looking for.